# Removing Characters from a string with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to know if there is any way to just remove backslashes '\' from a string with PHP? For some reason, when I use mysqli_real_escape_string() the output text has a '\' before any apostrophes. I know I could you use a function to strip the slashes but I want to keep all forward slashes '/'.

Btw, I've already made sure magic quotes is turned off. The problem still persists.

Thanks

Comment: Why are you outputting text passed to `mysqli_real_escape_string`?

Comment: Use `str_replace()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Comment: have you tried preg_replace()

Comment: I'm not. I'm using it to input text. I'm outputting it from the database table.

Comment: The whole point of using `mysqli_real_escape_string()` is to add backslashes before all the special characters. You need backslashes before apostrophes, to prevent them from terminating a string when you substitute into a SQL command.

Comment: That's why I want to remove them AFTER.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a function for that and it is surprisingly called `stripslashes`

Here it goes: http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php

- It will keep your forward slashes if that's what you're worrying about

Comment: I already gave you +1, but I'm sure it would be easier for many if you linked to the manual page for that function.

Answer (score 0):

```
QUERY:-remove backslashes '\' from a string but I want to keep all forward slashes '/'. 
After hard working and googled if find result of your query:-

$path="uploads\\folder_name\\ankur/like you"; /////string
echo str_replace("\\"," ",$path);

output:-uploads folder_name ankur/like you
```